# Proof that limit of sequence is unique

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am learning real analysis on my own from this book http://books.google.co.in/books?id=TZ-NAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false

On page 33 , i do not get proof of that limit of sequence is unique

Can anyone help me with this

Thanks

Comment: I can't see the proof and so will have to guess at what it's doing. The "standard" approach is to assume that, in fact, the limit of a sequence is *not* unique. Then $\lim x_n = x^*$ *and* $\lim x_n = y^*$ for some $x^*, y^*$. But then $x^* = \lim x_n = y^*$ so that $x^* = y^*$, which is to say that $x^*$ and $y^*$ are the same number, and thus limits are indeed unique.

Comment: This way is equivalent to:
Suppose $x^*$ is a limit of the sequence $(x_n)$ and suppose that $y^*$ is a limit of the sequence $x_n$ and suppose (for the sake of a contradiction that $x^* \neq y^*$. Because of our first supposition, there exists $N_1 \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $n \geq N_1, \|x_n - x^*\| < \varepsilon/2$. Similarly, there exists $N_2 \geq N_1$ such that for all $n \geq N_2, \|x_n - y^*\| < \varepsilon/2$. 

Then it follows for any $n \geq N_2$ that $\|x^* - y^*\| = \|x^* - x_n + x_n - y^*\| \leq \|x^* - x_n\| + \|x_n - y^*\| < \varepsilon/2 + \varepsilon/2 = \varepsilon$

Comment: yes this is clear .I meant other proof given on page 33

Comment: I cannot see the other proof, since Google Books omits certain pages.

Comment: @K.Dutta The book is not free. I can't read past page 31.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok...the other proof is basically trying to say the following.

If possible let $x$ and $y$ be two limits of a convergent sequence $(x_n)$. Let $x\neq y$, then either $x<y$ or $x>y$.

Let us assume that $x<y$. Then you can find an $\epsilon >0$ such that the intervals $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ and $(y-\epsilon,y+\epsilon)$ are disjoint. (I think this is not hard to see that such an $\epsilon$ exists, in particular you can take your $\epsilon$ to be $\frac{y-x}{2}$).

Now apply the definition of the limit to this $\epsilon$, i.e., there exists $n_1$ and $n_2$ such that $|x_n-x|<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq n_1$ and $|x_n-y|<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq n_2$. In particular, for $N = n_1+n_2$ you will get $x_N \in (x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ and $x_N \in (y-\epsilon,y+\epsilon)$, which contradicts the fact that these two intervals were disjoint (because this was how we chose our $\epsilon$).

Similarly, you can arrive at contradiction when $x>y$.

Comment: We have started with disjoint intervals and then we arrive at contradiction that they are not disjoint .But how does this show  uniqueness about limits

Comment: see...the contradiction we are getting is only because of the assumption that $x\neq y$. So, this assumption has to be false, i.e., we must have $x=y$ which shows that the limit is unique.